Why is my flexbox bigger than the size of its items?
I have the following code.  How can I get the card div to only be as high as the text within it instead of taking up the entire height of the container div minus the margin I set for it?


html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100dvh;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100dvh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: brown;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    menu
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    main
    <div class="card">
      my card
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>

</div>



I have tried everything I can think of the only thing that works is if I don't make the containing div grow to take up all the vertical space.  I want it do that but don't want the card to take up all the vertical space.  I only want it to be as big as it needs to be.

A default setting on flex containers is align-items: stretch, which makes flex items stretch the full length of the cross axis. Simply override this setting with align-items: flex-start. MDN
Add this to your code:
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: brown;
  align-items: flex-start;  /* NEW */
}



html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100dvh;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100dvh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: brown;
  align-items: flex-start;  /* NEW */
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    menu
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    main
    <div class="card">
      my card
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>

</div>




Hi Michael: Thanks for the feedback.  That didn't work for me though.  It just made the card wider and take up the whole area instead of making it smaller.

The rendering in the modified code I posted in my answer doesn't match your description. Perhaps post a demo of the problem.



html,  
body {  
  margin: 0;  
  height: 100dvh;  
  background-color: darkkhaki;  
}  

.wrapper {  
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;  
  margin: auto;  
  max-width: 1000px;  
  background-color: aqua;  
  height: 100dvh;  
}  

.header {  
  display: flex;  
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: purple;  
}  

.menu {  
  display: flex;  
  height: 30px;  
  background-color: blue;  
}  

.main {  
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column; /* Change to column */  
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* Allow main to fill available space */  
  background-color: brown;  
}  

.card {  
  /* Remove display: flex; so it will take height only according to contents */  
  margin: 20px;  
  background-color: orange;  
}  

.footer {  
  display: flex;  
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: green;  
}
<div class="wrapper">  
  <div class="header">  
    Header  
  </div>  

  <div class="menu">  
    menu  
  </div>  

  <div class="main">  
    main  
    <div class="card">  
      my card  
    </div>  
  </div>  

  <div class="footer">  
    footer  
  </div>  
</div>



Remove the flex style from the .card div. By default, a flex child element takes the available space, which causes the card to grow.
Set the .main div's flex-direction to column and allow the .card div to naturally size itself according to its content.

Hi oneli:  Thanks for the feedback.  Those changes made it only as tall as it needed to be but the width still stretched out from side to side.

The issue is that main is a flex, and this line: flex: 1 1 auto is scaling its children to fill the container.
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: brown;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
}

If you'd like the card to remain a flexbox, you should add width: fit-content; to .card to make sure that the width shrinks to fit its content + padding.
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: brown;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
}


Hi AntXD:  Thanks for the suggestions!  I could see where changing the display to inline-block changed anything.  Adding height: fit-content instead of width: fit-content did work.
